# How do I retain object property values between more than one strongly typed view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

- I have one view model called `ExampleViewModel`.
- I have one controller called `ExampleController`
- I have two views called `Page1` and `Page2`.

Both views are strongly typed with `ExampleViewModel`.

`ExampleViewModel` contains two properties, `Name` and `Age`.

- `Page1` captures data for the property `Name`.
- `Page2` captures data for the property `Age`.

When I visit `page1`, I fill in the textbox for the `Name` property and hit a 'Next' button which will post the data to the controller.

When debugging you can see the data is posted OK. The data sent back to the post function is a `ExampleViewModel` object. Then I pass that same object to into `Page2`.

When I then visit `page2`, I fill in the textbox for the `Age` property and hit a `Back` button which will post the data to the controller.

The problem here is when you look into the `ExampleViewModel` object that was posted back, the `Name` property value which was set in `Page1` is now lost, and only `Page2` data is submitted (`Age` property).

**How do I keep property values of the same object that are passed between views?**

**ExampleViewModel**

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**ExampleController**

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult PostMethod (ExampleViewModel formData, FormCollection form, string command)
    {
        string newView = "";
        string newController = "";

        Session["formData"] = formData;

        if (command.ToLower() == "back")
        {
            newView = form["PreviousAction"];
            newController = form["PreviousController"];
        }
        else if (command.ToLower() == "next")
        {
            newView = form["NextAction"];
            newController = form["NextController"];
        }

        return RedirectToAction(newView, newController);
    }

    public ActionResult Page1()
    {
        return GetView();
    }

    public ActionResult Page2()
    {
        return GetView();
    }

    private ViewResult GetView()
    {
        ExampleViewModel formData = (ExampleViewModel)Session["formData"];

        if (formData != null)
        {
            return View(formData);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Page 1 View**

```
@model ExampleProject.ViewModels.ExampleViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostMethod", "Example", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.Label("Your name")
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

   <input id="ButtonNext" type="submit" name="Command" value="Next" />

   @Html.Hidden("nextaction", "page2")
   @Html.Hidden("nextcontroller", "example")
}
```

**Page 2 View**

```
@model ExampleProject.ViewModels.ExampleViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostMethod", "Example", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.Label("Age")
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)

   <input id="ButtonBack" type="submit" name="Command" value="Back" />

   @Html.Hidden("previousaction", "page1")
   @Html.Hidden("previouscontroller", "example")
}
```

Comment: You page 2 view does not render an input for the `Name` property of `ExampleViewModel`

Comment: Welcome to the stateless web... try hidden form values, sessions or databases.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you post back Page2, you no longer have Name set as it is not persisted anywhere.

One way to persist this is, in your Page2 view, you also add a HiddenField for your name property, so that when you post your Page2 back to the server, the Name field will still be bound.

```
@model ExampleProject.ViewModels.ExampleViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostMethod", "Example", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.Label("Age")
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)

  <input id="ButtonBack" type="submit" name="Command" value="Back" />

  @Html.Hidden("previousaction", "page1")
  @Html.Hidden("previouscontroller", "example")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right way to do it is

I can think of two easy ways.

i) Use Wizard kind of Clientside javascript control(or Jquery,Angularjs etc) and postback on the last Submit(Step) 
          or 
    Just Show/Hide different sections of page on browser through javascript and Submit (postback) as Final Step.

Here is an example [Link](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples)

OR

ii) Save the Object on every postback.

If you are saving these values, I mean saving 'Name' on Page1 Postback, then on page2 Postback you should just retrieve the saved object from db and just set 'age' to the Model and save it back to db.

Only update the values of Model that user is allowed to update through each Postback.

I would **not** recommend to saving this object in session.